# Recursive querystring parser

Tags: php, parsing, query-string

I'm in need of a function that will parse a querystring into a multidimensional array. 
The querystring could look somewhat like this:

```
?fields=incidents:(id,shortdescription,action,request);people:(unid,name)&format=json
```

The array returned should like like this:

```
array(
   'fields' => array(
      'incidents' => array(
         'id',
         'shortdescription',
         'action',
         'request'
      ),
      'people' => array(
         'unid',
         'name'
      ),
   ),
   'format' => 'json'
);
```

I want the separators to be dynamic, so they would reside in an array like this:

```
$separators = array(';', ':', ',');
```

The order of the seperators in this array will determine the order in which the querystring is parsed.

Someone have anything like this handy???

Regards,

Mark

Comment: ...what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

```
$final = array();
$keys = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {

    $final[$key] = $value;

    $child = explode(";", $value);
    foreach ($child as $key2 => $value2) {
        $final[$key][$key2] = array();

        $subchild = explode(":", $value2);
        foreach ($subchild as $key3 => $value3) {
            $subsubchild = explode(",", $value3);
            $final[$key][$key2][$key3] = $subsubchild;
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test this, but hopefully get the idea of where I'm going...

This could be updated to create a function that accepts a delimiter to make it truly recursive so that rather than having a loop inside a loop inside a loop you could call this function...

Answer (score 0):

Myself, I came up with this:

```
protected static function split( $value, $sep = ',' )
{   
    if ( str_contains( $value, $sep ) ) 
        $value = explode( $sep, $value );

    return $value;
} 

protected static function multi_split( $value )
    {
        $arr = array();

        // Do we have multiple models?
        $parts = static::split( $value, '+' );        
        if ( count( $parts ) > 1 ) {
            foreach( $parts as $part ) {
                $models = static::split( $part, ':' ); 
                if ( count( $models ) > 1 ) {
                    $fields = static::split( trim($models[1], '()'), ',' );                   
                    $arr[$models[0]] = $fields;   
                }   
            }             

            return $arr;  
        } 

        // Do we have a single model?
        $parts = static::split( $value, ':' ); 
        if ( count( $parts ) > 1 ) {
            $fields = static::split( trim($parts[1], '()'), ',' );               
            $arr[$parts[0]] = $fields;

            return $arr;  
        } 

        // Do we have a comma-separated param?
        $parts = static::split( $value, ',' );
        if ( count( $parts ) > 1 ) 
            return $parts; 

        // Do we have a string param?
        return $value;

    }
```

There is a lot of repetition that I would like to get rid off. Also, it is not very dynamic yet!